# Isekai(?) Japanese-style light novel about a banished artisan who harnessed the powers of Fire, Light, Water, Wind, and Earth

Tags: story-identification, novel, isekai

This was a Japanese-style light novel. It was written in English and I would have read it online.

The story follows a man who passionately devoted himself to his homeland but was banished despite the contributions he did for his country. Unfortunately, I have forgotten the banish reason as well.

He was later told to travel to the demon world, and although I don't know whether our main character knows of this, but his superiors want him to die in said realm he was banished to. He suddenly obtains the darkness element upon stepping in said realm and meets a girl....I think? basically a minion or subordinate of the demon king. He then asks if the Demon King will accept him as a resident if he were to create useful stuff for the overall welfare of the demons. The Demon King agreed.

If I am not wrong, the main character of this light novel harnessed the powers of the 6 elements (Fire, Water/Ice, Earth, Wind, Light & Dark) he possess to recreate the various machines/creations that originate from earth for the Demon King. For the following hint, it is not confirmed, but one of those products is a washing machine.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: well, thanks for your advice and I have added as many details as I can. Sad that I can't remember any names tho

Comment: Added [isekai] tag, which seems relevant and is useful in both identifying/answering this kind of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it myself after asking on Reddit. The name is ***[The Creation Alchemist Enjoys Freedom -If I Am Exiled From My Hometown, I Can Make Magic Items With Transcendent Effects at the Knees of the Demon Lord-](https://www.novelupdates.com/series/the-creation-alchemist-enjoys-freedom-if-i-am-exiled-from-my-hometown-i-can-make-magic-items-with-transcendent-effects-at-the-knees-of-the-demon-lord/)***.

From [Anime-Planet](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/souzou-renkinjutsushi-wa-jiyuu-wo-ouka-suru-kokyou-wo-tsuihou-saretara-maou-no-ohizamoto-de-chouzetsu-kouka-no-magic-item-zukuri-houdai-ni-narimashita):

> Thor Regus, a boy who lived in the empire, was banished to the territory of the Demon Lord by the hands of his father, the Duke. The reason was that he could only use alchemy and didn’t have any combat skills. The empire was a military country, and those without combat skills were discriminated against. That is why the empire decided to make him a hostage and sacrifice to the Demon Territory. This is a story about an exiled boy who transcends Empires and Heroes and transforms the Demon Territory into a civilized power.